# Using Router Guards to redirect the user

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to redirect the user. If a cookie exists, they should not have access to pages /login, /register and / (homepage). So they should always get redirected to the page /search. If no cookie exists, they should not have access to the page /search, so they should get redirected to the homepage.

### This is what I want:

**User is NOT logged in**

```
| Page     | Redirect to  |
|----------|--------------|
| Search   | Home         |
```

**User is logged in**

```
| Page     | Redirect to  |
|----------|--------------|
| Login    | Search       |
| Register | Search       |
| Home     | Search       |
```

I am using `this.router.navigateByUrl('/search');` to redirect the user from the homepage to /search page but that doesn't work. The console of my browsers prints *test* once every second. The status bar of Chrome tells me either *Waiting for localhost...* or *Connecting...*. This repeats all over time. I guess this is because I use the same guard for multiple components.

**login.guard.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {SearchComponent} from '../search/search/search.component';
import {CookieService} from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import {LoginService} from './login.service';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private searchComponent: SearchComponent, private cookieService: CookieService, private loginService: LoginService, private router: Router, private location: Location) {
  }
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): any {
    return this.hasAccess();
  }

  hasAccess() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.loginService.hasCookie(this.cookieService.get('login')).subscribe(hasCookie => {
        if (hasCookie === 1) {
          return new Promise(() => {
            this.loginService.getCookie().subscribe(cookieFromServer => {
              if (cookieFromServer === this.cookieService.get('login')) {
                if (this.location.path() === '/login' || this.location.path() === '/register') {
                  this.router.navigateByUrl('');
                  return resolve(false);
                } else if (this.location.path() === '') {
                  console.log('test');
                  this.router.navigateByUrl('/search'); // <------- This line keeps repeating
                  return resolve(false);
                }
                return resolve(true);
              } else {
                this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
                return resolve(false);
              }
            });
          });
        }
        if (this.location.path() === '/login' || this.location.path() === '/register') {
          return resolve(true);
        }
        if (this.location.path() === '/login' || this.location.path() === '/register') {
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
        } else if (this.location.path() === '') {
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/search');
        }
        return resolve(false);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

**app-routing.modules.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {SearchComponent} from './search/search/search.component';
import {RegisterComponent} from './register/register.component';
import {LoginComponent} from './login/login.component';
import {LoginGuard} from './login/login.guard';
import {ProfileComponent} from './profile/profile.component';
import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard] },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard] },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard] },
  { path: 'search', component: SearchComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard] },
  { path: 'edit-profile', component: ProfileComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled' })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of theories here.  I've seen this work many times very similar to this.  I think the basic use case is Page X has a AuthGuard and it will either allow and return true, or it will redirect them to "Login Page" and return false to deny access.  Also Login Page doesn't have an auth guard so there is no reason to "loop" it will just end when it hits "Login Page".

I guess what is different here is:
1) I don't think you're ever returning true 
2) It's never kicking them to a page like "Login Page" that has no auth guard.

my theory is because of 1 & 2 combined the logic can never complete so it's infinite looping.

So a couple of things you could try, try to remove the auth guard from the /search page, that would let the loop end because it would finally hit a page it had access to.

OR HOPEFULLY, it's as easy as adjusting the logic so you return TRUE from your auth guard where it is repeating, and that will hopefully also allow the loop to end.

Let me know if you have any luck there.

Basically:
I think then anytime you have return resolve(false); you must navigate to the login page and if you go to any other page resolve(true)

Comment: You are right. If I remove the auth guard from the /search page, then it works and there is no longer a loop. But I need the auth guard for the /search page. The user should not have access to that page if they are not logged in.

Comment: i think then anytime you have return resolve(false); you must navigate to the login page and if you go to any other page resolve(true)